# Why my routes in Sitecore 9 doesn't work?

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

Trying to apply custom routing in Sitecore 9 using following documentation: 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/use_mvc_routing.
But no luck, ends up on 404 page. Seems like route is registered, but something is wrong with parameters:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Product",
        url: "product-offering/{category}/{product}",
        defaults: new { scItemPath = "product-offering/{product}", scKeysToIgnore = new string[] { "category" } });
}
```

Perhaps someone faced with this issue in Sitecore 9, because this piece of code works for Sitecore 8.2.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @tidmutt Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem here is a dash in the item name.
In the "App_Config/Sitecore.config" file, there is the following config:

**replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-"**.

As you can see, names are intentionally modified. With this setting enabled, it is not allowed to have content items with names that contain dashes. Well, they are allowed, but it is pointless:

1) Let's say you have an item called "product-offering" with dashes in its name.

2) When a link is generated for this item, all spaces are replaced with dashes according to the above setting, so the URL becomes: http://hostname/product-offering (in this case, the same name remains).

3) When such URL is requested, for retrieving the related content item, opposite name transformation is performed - dashes are replaced with spaces, according to the above settings. Name "product-offering" becomes "product offering"
4) There is no item with name "product offering", so the 404 is received.

Thus, I see two options for resolving the reported behavior:

-> either replace dashes with spaces in names

-> or comment out the above mentioned Sitecore.config setting.

Answer (score -1):

In Sitecore, there is no use of visual studio route.config file ,  because in sitecore all routes are define in terms of pipeline in web.config in Views folder.
Hope this answer will help you.